# model validation messages - in which project should I put resources?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have in my solution 3 projects: UI, DAL and BLL. In DAL I have models with validation attributes and in UI project i have viewmodels with validation attributes, for example:

```
public class Note
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = ?????)]        
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

So should I add resource file with validation messages in UI project or create new project?? Which approach is better??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Project and add is a reference to the Projects which needs a usage of resources

- Project.DAL
- Project.BLL
- Project.UI
- Project.Resources